# How to enable multiple compiler versions in solc js?

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler, solcjs

I'm trying to compile contract `A`(located in A.sol) that has a dependency on contract `B`(located in B.sol) using `solc-js`,
where `A` has solidity version ***0.8.0*** and `B` version ***0.7.6***. The solcjs version that I'm using is ***0.7.6*** and so `A` fails to compile with error:

```
A.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.6+commit.7338295f.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

I'm using the following command to compile contract `A`:

```
solcjs --bin ./contracts/A.sol --optimize --optimize-runs 1000
```

Updating `solc-js` to version ***0.8.0*** now results in the same issue but now `B` fails to compile instead.

The issue appears to be that each file/contract should be compiled with their respective compilers, how can I make `solc-js` compile with the required versions?

Answer (score 0):

in B.sol, just update the solidity version

from `0.7.6` to `0.8.0`

Comment: That's not my question. Doing so will introduce breaking changes to contract B.

Comment: Oh, yeah I understood. But at least I dont know any other way. 

But  from 0.7.6 to 0.8.0 , will remove you errors.